# lightswitch html client trying to refresh page TypeError

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Im getting an TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'Summary' of Undefined.

I am trying to refresh a page in my html client.

Do I need to upgrade from jquery 1.3.0 to 1.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to refresh pages in a SPA (Single Page Application) such as LightSwitch HTML.  When you refresh the page, it loses state information, and objects that were once valid are now set back to their default state of null.

After the refresh you're attempting to access a property on an object that is undefined.  (The property may typically exist when the object is valid, but because the object is null or undefined, the property is considered undefined.)

An example of this is when you lookup an Object by an invalid Id and instead of returning a valid Object, a null Object is returned.